# Why can't I refer to an instance of a class by name within a method?

Tags: c++

```
class mail
{

void reg();
.
.
};

void mail::reg()
{

filout.write((char *)&obj,sizeof(obj)); // error occurring on compilation. undefined sysmbol obj

}

int main()
{


{  //local block

mail obj;
.
.
obj.reg();

} //end of local block


}// end of main
```

How can i rectify this error. Is the object destroyed when i call a memeber function.
My understanding is that obj is destroyed when the block in which it is defined ends

How can i write the obj into the file in the reg()

thanks

Full code as per requested:

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int user;           // to keep a track of no. of users

class mail
{
public:
    char un[25];             // user name
    char pd[25];             // passsword
    // no. of inbox messages
    int ino;                 // no. of sent messages
    int sno;
    char isbj[25][25];
    char ssbj[25][25];
    char imsg[25][50];
    char smsg[25][50];       // character array to store inbox and sent messages
    void reg();             // func to sign up
    void signin();
    mail()
    {}
    ~mail()
    {
        cout<<"DESTRUCTER AT WORK\N";
        getch();
    }         // menu available after sign in
};          // object for 10 users

void mail::reg()
{
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter user name ( enter unique name )\n";
    gets(un);
    cout<<"Enter password\n";
    gets(pd);
    ofstream filout;
    filout.open("email",ios::app||ios::binary);
    if(!filout)
    {
        cout<<"cannot open file\n";
    }
    else
    {
        ino=-1;
        sno=-1;

        filout.write((char *)&obj,sizeof(obj));
        filout.close();


    }


    cout<<"You are now registered. Plz login\n";
    getch();

}        // end of sign up or register func



void mail::signin()
{
    int f,i;
    char subj[25],message[50],usrnm[25];       // temporary varibles to store

start:
    clrscr();
    cout<<"1.compose \n2.inbox \n3.Sent\n4.logout";
    cout<<"\nEnter ur choice\n";

    int ch;
    cin>>ch;

    switch(ch)
    {

    case 1:
        cout<<"enter username\n";
        gets(usrnm);

        {            // beginning of local loop
            mail temp;

            ifstream filein;
            filein.open("email",ios::in|ios::binary);
            if(!filein)
            {
                cout<<"Unable to open file to read\n";
            }
            else
            {

                filein.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(temp));
                while(filein)
                {
                    if(strcmp(usrnm,temp.un)==0)
                    {

                        cout<<" User name valid\n";


                        f=1;


                        cout<<"Enter subject\n";
                        gets(subj);
                        cout<<"Enter message\n";
                        gets(message);
                        temp.ino++;
                        strcpy(temp.isbj[temp.ino],subj);

                        strcpy(temp.imsg[temp.ino],message);  // copying message to recepient inbox

                        sno++;
                        strcpy(ssbj[sno],subj);
                        strcpy(smsg[sno],message);  // copying messages to sender sent folder

                        cout<<"Your message has been sent successfully\n";
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }


                    filein.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(temp));
                }               // end of while

            }
            filein.close();


            mail temp1;

            long pos;
            fstream fio("email",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
            pos=fio.tellg();
            fio.read((char*)&temp1,sizeof(temp1));

            while(fio)
            {

                if(strcmp(un,temp1.un)==0)
                {

                    fio.seekg(pos);

                    fio.write((char*)&obj,sizeof(obj));
                    break;
                }
                pos=fio.tellg();
                fio.read((char*)&temp1,sizeof(temp1));
            }
            fio.close();

            mail temp2;


            fio.open("email",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
            pos=fio.tellg();
            fio.read((char*)&temp2,sizeof(temp2));

            while(fio)
            {

                if(strcmp(temp.un,temp2.un)==0)
                {

                    fio.seekg(pos);

                    fio.write((char*)&temp,sizeof(temp));
                    break;
                }
                pos=fio.tellg();
                fio.read((char*)&temp2,sizeof(temp2));
            }
            fio.close();

        } // end of block



        if(f==0)
            cout<<"invalid user. Please enter a valid user name\n";
        getch();
        break;

    case 2:
        if(ino<0)
            cout<<"There are no messages in your inbox\n";
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<=ino;i++)
            {
                cout<<"\nMessage "<<i+1<<"\n";   // printing inbox messages

                puts(isbj[i]);

                puts(imsg[i]);


            }
        }
        getch();
        break;

    case 3:
        if(sno<0)
            cout<<"There are no sent messages\n";
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<=sno;i++)
            {

                cout<<"\nMessage "<<i+1<<"\n";
                puts(ssbj[i]);
                puts(smsg[i]);

            }
        }
        getch();
        break;

    case 4:
        cout<<"Logout sucess\n";
        return;


    default : cout<<"wrong choice\n";

    } // end of switch

    goto start;

} // end of signin




void screen(void);
void signup(void);


void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char usrnm[25],pwd[25],s[25],c;
    int i;
m:

    clrscr();
    screen();
    gotoxy(30,4);
    c=getch();

    if(c=='i'||c=='I')               //if user opts to sign in
    {

        gotoxy(62,11);
        gets(usrnm);
        gotoxy(62,13);


        for(i=0;i< 25;i++)                   // getting password
        {
            if( i < 0)
                i=0;
            pwd[i]=getch();
            if(pwd[i]=='\b')
            { i-=2;
            cout<<"\b \b";
            continue;
            }

            if(pwd[i]=='\r')
                break;
            cout<<"*";
        }
        pwd[i]='\0';
        clrscr();

        int f;
        {                       // local block

            mail obj;


            ifstream filein;
            filein.open("email",ios::in|ios::binary);
            if(!filein)
            {
                cout<<"Unable to open file to read\n";
            }
            else
            {
                filein.seekg(0);

                filein.read((char *)&obj,sizeof(obj));
                while(filein)
                {
                    if(strcmp(usrnm,obj.un)==0)
                    {
                        f=1;
                        if(strcmp(pwd,obj.pd)==0)
                        {

                            obj.signin();
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<"wrong password\n";
                            getch();

                            break;
                        }


                    } // end of if
                    else
                    {
                    }
                    filein.read((char *)&obj,sizeof(obj));
                }               // end of while


                filein.close();
            } // end of else

        }


        if(f==0)
            cout<<"Wrong username or password\n";
        getch();
        goto m;
    }
    else if(c=='s'||c=='S')       // user opts to sign up
    {
        signup();
        getch();
        goto m;
    }
    else if(c=='e'||c=='E')       // user choose to exit
        exit(0);
    else
    {
        clrscr();
        cout<<"you have entered a wrong key. please check and try again\n";

        getch();
        goto m;
    }

}  //end of main


void signup()                   // sign up function
{



    int t;
    clrscr();
    {
        mail obj;
        ifstream filin;
        filin.open("user.txt",ios::ate);
        if(!filin)
        {
            cout<<"cannot open file\n";
        }
        else
        {
            filin.seekg(0);
            filin>>t;
        }

        filin.close();

        user=t;
        ++user;                     // incrementing no. users

        ofstream filout;
        filout.open("user.txt",ios::out);
        if(!filout)
        {
            cout<<"cannot open file\n";
        }
        else
        {
            filout.seekp(0);
            filout<<user;
        }

        filin.close();

        obj.reg();

    }  // end of block

    return;

}       // end of sign up



void screen()                // function for login screen
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"*";
    cout<<" SuperMail                             New to SuperMial ? Create an Account     ";
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"*";
    cout<<" Press S To Sign up                    Already have a account Press I to sign in";
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"-";
    gotoxy(1,6);
    cout<<"\n\n\n\n Super mail is built on the idea that \n it can be more intuitive,efficient and \n useful and may be even fun:\n\n Lots of space\n\n Less spam";
    gotoxy(1,22);
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"-";
    gotoxy(32,23);
    cout<<"PRESS E TO EXIT";
    gotoxy(1,24);
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"-";
    gotoxy(50,10);
    cout<<"-------------------------------";
    gotoxy(50,11);
    cout<<"| USERNAME :                  |";
    gotoxy(50,12);
    cout<<"-------------------------------";
    gotoxy(50,13);
    cout<<"| PASSWORD :                  |";
    gotoxy(50,14);
    cout<<"-------------------------------";
}
```

There are other error also
Thanks

Comment: what about real code and real error messages?

Comment: Its really long. You wouldn't care to read it. So i shortened it

Comment: Let us decide whether we want to read it or not. Always post full error messages!

Comment: @user1889099: If you are able to decide what information is necessary to solve that problem, and what not, I wonder why you weren't able to solve the problem yourself...

Comment: Okay. Im sorry. I have posted the full code.

Comment: Reduce your example to make it minimal.

Comment: What we were trying to suggest: Always strive to post a http://sscce.org/

Comment: [Lol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953045/c-file-handling-error). Cross posting is not welcome here (even if it would be possible). Especially not under different user names. Please take your time and look how others ask questions here and read the FAQ.

Comment: Sorry. Both are different issues. Why did u bar me from asking qns. Should i delete this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is not destroyed, but the name `obj` isn't available inside `reg()` - that's just what you named your object inside `main()`.

You can refer to the current object inside member functions via `*this`, but you can also access members directly.

Comment: So the code would be filout.write((char *)&obj,sizeof(*this)); Right ?

Comment: @mohdrafi `&obj`? Or `this`?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to `obj` in `reg()` method using `this` (e.g. this->data) pointer as `reg()` is a member in mail class which `obj` is an instance of.

Answer (score 0):

Obj is just a local name for the variable.  When you are inside the class function, you can access 'obj' (which is the current instance of the class) by using this. The keyword `this` is a pointer to the instance of the class.  You can do:

```
this->foo();  //  called a smart pointer
//or
*this.foo();  //  deference the variable
```

Answer (score 0):

obj is  **just a variable name**. You do not want to write obj in the file. What you want is to  **write the current classes variables** in the file. Simply use the member variables in the method as they will be available. 
Or if you have external method something like this

```
 void write(mail* a)
```

, then you need to call it as

```
write(this).
```

If the method which writes the object is the member function like

```
void mail::write()
```

, then simply call write() and first point applies to the method write.

EDIT  :- You can't do

```
 filout.write((char *)&obj,sizeof(obj));
```

. This will print out some gibberish. Instead of this try printing the contents of individual variable.

Comment: I want to write the entire contents of obj into the file. Iam not sure of how writing members individually and if it effects rest of the code